# List subscribedSkus - licensing channel(s)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I know I can get a list of skus/licences assigned to a tenant but is it possible to see what licensing channel(s) the licenses where ordered through such as CSP, Open EA ect....?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we have that information on the subscribedSkus entity type.  Can you provide some more details or scenarios as to why you need this information please?

Thanks,